# When trying to add a codepipeline stage in cdk2 I get a TypeError reading "region" despite explicitly stated in the import and pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Here is the snippet of the code...

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
const codepipeline = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline');
const codepipeline_actions = require('aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions');

...

// Codepipeline 
// Create a CodePipeline pipeline
const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  env: {
    account: config.account,
    region: config.region,
  },
  pipelineName: config.pipelineName,
  crossAccountKeys: false,
  restartExecutionOnUpdate: true,
});

// Create Source Artifact
const sourceOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact('SourceOutput');

const sourceAction = new codepipeline_actions.S3SourceAction({
  actionName: 'S3Source',
  bucket: config.bucketName,
  bucketKey: config.bucketKey,
  output: sourceOutput,
  trigger: codepipeline_actions.S3Trigger.POLL,
});


// add source Stage to the Pipeline...
pipeline.addStage({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  stageName: 'Source',
  actions: [sourceAction],
});

console.log(addSourceStage);

console.log("region", config.region);
// //const buildOutput = new codepipeline.Artifact();
const deployAction = new codepipeline_actions.CodeDeployServerDeployAction({
  actionName: 'CodeDeploy',
  input: sourceOutput,
  deploymentGroup: codedeploymentGroup,
});

// add build Stage to the Pipeline...
pipeline.addStage({
  stageName: 'Deploy',
  actions: [deployAction],
});
```

...

Error as below ==>

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'region')
at get effectiveRegion[as effectiveRegion]**(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / private / rich - action.js: 1: 1063)
at get isCrossRegion[as isCrossRegion](/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / private / rich - action.js: 1: 498)
at Pipeline.ensureReplicationResourcesExistFor(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / pipeline.js: 1: 8351)
at Pipeline._attachActionToPipeline(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / pipeline.js: 1: 7708)
at Stage.attachActionToPipeline(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / private / stage.js: 1: 3087)
at Stage.addAction(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / private / stage.js: 1: 1716)
at new Stage(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / private / stage.js: 1: 678)
at Pipeline.addStage(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / node_modules / aws - cdk - lib / aws - codepipeline / lib / pipeline.js: 1: 6662)
**at new CodedeployCodepipelineS3CdkStack(/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / lib / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk - stack.js: 207: 14)**
at Object. < anonymous > (/Users/userx / AWS - CDK / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk / bin / codedeploy - codepipeline - s3 - cdk.js: 9: 1)

Node.js v18 .0 .0

Subprocess exited with error 1

Please note that from the above error, 207: 14 line starts at

```
pipeline.addStage({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  stageName: 'Source',
  actions: [sourceAction],
});
```

I Tried adding region in require aws module

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});

also added region in 
const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
  env: {
    account: config.account,
    region: config.region,
  },
```

....
and in

```
pipeline.addStage({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  stageName: 'Source',
  actions: [sourceAction],
});
```

None of the above seems to resolve the TypeError issue.

Comment: SDK will not help you with CDK. `region` is not a prop you can pass to `addStage`, so that will not work. Similary, the `Pipeline` constructor does not accept an `env` prop that you're passing, so that will not work either. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The region and account variable is already in the "bootstrap" file that calls this stack. For some reason the codepipeline construct doesn't recognize it so I tried all the above options. part of the error throws out code from cdk's action.js which seems to be checking for the env. get isCrossRegion() { return !actionDimensionSameAsPipelineDimension(this.effectiveRegion, this.pipeline.env.region)
  }
  get isCrossAccount() { return !actionDimensionSameAsPipelineDimension(this.effectiveAccount, this.pipeline.env.account)
  }

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. Passing props that don't exist will never work, though. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to use s3action to get the source package from S3 and deploy in the next stage using codedeploy in the code pipeline.

Comment: Start by fixing your calls according to the docs. Don't pass the props that don't exist. For the props that do exist, pass the expected type (`bucket` expects an `s3.IBucket`, and I'm assuming `config.bucktName` is a string).

Comment: Thank you. Yes the bucket is a string which is from the config file. Let me try the above if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Go through all the classes you are using and check the docs to see if the types of props you are passing match what's expected. And make sure to reflect all the fixes in the question body.

Comment: I came across this Doc. The region of the action will be determined by the region the bucket itself is in. When using a newly created bucket, that region will be taken from the stack the bucket belongs to; for an imported bucket, you can specify the region explicitly:

const sourceBucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketAttributes(this, 'SourceBucket', {
  bucketName: 'my-bucket',
  region: 'ap-southeast-1',
});  So I will try this and see if this resolves the original region error...

Comment: When I output the region after explicitly setting it in above code, I get region as  undefined which is probably why when calling sourceAction it's failing at region undefined. So it may be a bug with CDK...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help here - the code in the question has too many errors and is confusing. Can you replace it with an example we can reproduce that only uses the correct props?

Comment: After a few trial and error, I was able to fix the module errors that I was getting by downgrading my nodejs to 16.3.0 version (from the supported list popup menu when I ran the cdk synth) and did a new project init. The cdk version is also a downgraded version compared to the latest I was using. Copied and code over and cdk synth is working fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see **region** as a property of StageOptions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.StageOptions.html

According to the docs, you should add it in your actions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.ActionProperties.html

Comment: Thank you for the comment and clarifications. Yes the StageOptions doesnt have the region. For the Actionproperties I wont be needing it since I use the codepipeline_actions. I am not sure how Actionproperties could be used here.